# Issue with resize and stty on remote ssh script?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, ksh

**Scenario**: Source host (Solaris 5.10, KSH), im trying to run the following script named **sample.ksh** on source

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x
Rediscover ()
{
ssh user@hostB ./scripts/test.ksh
}
Rediscover
exit 0
```

Remote Host: Linux (bash shell), i have the following script called **test.ksh**

```
#!/bin/bash -x
resize
stty -a
exit
```

Issue: I can run the test.ksh without any issues directly on Linux host but when i try to run it remotely from solaris i am getting the follwoing error.

```
root@hostA# ./sample.ksh
+ Rediscover
+ resize
resize:  can't open terminal /dev/tty
+ stty -a
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
+ exit
+ exit 0
```

Why can't i see the output of resize and stty -a remotely ??

SSH keys were setup from A to B

Comment: Together with not being sure about this, I think the tty's play a role when you have an interactive session. By invoking a single script/executable from your ssh command line, you are telling the system, _this is not an interactive session_. In turn the system disregards the termcap or uses a very minimalistic one and stty command doesn't get involved. Again this is not from any document. Just my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force interactive session using `-tt` switch in your script:

```
ssh -tt user@hostB ./scripts/test.ksh
```

Otherwise the TTY on the `hostB` will not get allocated and you will get such errors.